# SP 2010 Custom Workflow - WinWF Internal Error, Terminating Workflow only when DelayActivity is used

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a custom workflow that I must start off with a delayActivity because the list activating the process has an event receiver that updates a column that I need prior to the workflow initializing.

When I use the DelayActivity, it delays fine and the Event Receiver finishes the update.  However, when the delay completes, the workflow fails.  The Hive Logs show:

- Workflow Infrastructure ----         88xr ------ Unexpected------    WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# 5ff955a1-5135-4e54-9e90-105e11952fee
- Workflow Infrastructure ----                 98d4 -----  Unexpected------    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I remove the Delay Activity the workflow kicks off fine, however the value I need isn't there because the event receiver isn't done updating.

I have tried launching the WF from the Event Receiver, but it just hangs.  A while Loop doesn't work either as it just keeps looping and holding the Event Receiver from completing the update.  I am kind of at my wits end here.  The DelayActivity seems like the best way to do this, but this error is making it impossible to use.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To whomever comes across this issue, I found the solution and unfortunately it is a bit of a PEBCAK error.  Right after the delay completed, I was referencing a value that was null.  However, in my defense I didn't realize that this was occurring.  This was due to the fact that I didn't realize that when a workflow sleeps between tasks\activities the breakpoints are not hit upon re-activating.  I am still looking into whether I can correct that or if it is just the way things are.

So anyways, if you are getting some weird error after a Delay Activity, look further in the code and see if it is possibly something else.